# java.io.FileNotFoundException cannot locate file under src folder

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I can open a file (while running in Eclipse Luna on a Mac) using a `Scanner`:

```
try {
    input = new Scanner(new File("./src/A-small-practice.in"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("ERROR: No File to read from");
}
```

... using relative path shown above. However, when I migrate it to Eclipse Neon on Windows 7, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`. I tried `src/`, `./src/`, `../src/` and `/src/`, none seems working. What should I do?

---

Temporary solution:

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("mac os x")){
    input = new Scanner(new File("./src/A-small-practice.in"));
}
else if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("wind")){
    /* Absolute path  */   
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work for any of those attempts?

Comment: try with full, absolute path. Your current directory may be not the one you think it is (it's almost sure it isn't if you didn't do anything to set it properly)

Comment: To my knowledge `./src/` should be able to do the job, but it is not working after I migrated to the new environment.

Comment: Have you printed out the user.dir to see where Java is looking?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the project's settings will potentially impact on this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the file is still located in `src` as I checked the Finder in the Mac and the Windows Explorer on the PC. I do not want to use the absolute path because I want it to be built in both environments

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the user.dir is the project folder under the `workspace` directory

Comment: @DylanChensky So what working directory is being set by the Run Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a simple output statement that will tell you what the program thinks is the current directory:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

If this is not what is expected, you can change Eclipse's working directory when it runs your application by going to Run->Run Configurations->[Your Project]->Arguments->Working Directory.

[image: Eclipse Run Configuration Working Directory]

Comment: That sounds more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: what does that "." do? it prints the absolute path of my project folder + `/.`

Comment: The "." is the current working directory of your program. The idea of printing it out is to make sure that the program's working directory is what you expect it to be (e.g. it might be erroneously set to the Eclipse home directory or the workspace root directory instead of your project directory). If the file is not in the working directory then the program won't be able to find it, and you should change the working directory appropriately (or move the file).

Comment: @Andreas my answer solves the problem of "Eclipse is running the program in the wrong working directory", which seems like a reasonable possibility for this question.

Comment: @DylanChensky Your own code uses `./src/A-small-practice.in`, which starts with a `.`, so how can you ask *"what does that "." do?"* Why did you start your file path with `./`, if you don't even know what it does?